# iptables firewall not allowing connection on port 8080 even if it is open (docker)

Tags: iptables, docker

I have opened my port 8080 in iptables and i am launching a nextcloud container where port 8080 is exposed and routed to nextcloud server on port 80 inside the container.

I cannot reach either localhost:8080 when i run docker locally or server_ip:8080 when i run docker on a remote server even if my port 8080 is open.

Docker has modified iptables after i ran my script to configure firewall.

How should i change the chain rules so it accepts connection to docker container?
(nextcloud is reachable on localhost:8080 if i put a INPUT policy to ACCEPT but server_ip:8080 is not reachable if i put INPUT policy to accept...)

Thank you

here is the iptables script:

```
#/bin/bash
set -ex

# Flush all existing rules, chains, and tables
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X


# set default policy to drop
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT


############### INPUT chain
## drop icmp
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

##  drop scans XMAS and NULL.
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,URG,PSH FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

## drop broadcast
iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP

## allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## allow local loopback
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#Server rules
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -i enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -i enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -i enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -i enp53s0 -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -i enp53s0 -j DROP

## On log les paquets en entrée.
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG


############### OUTPUT chain
# Allow outgoing traffic on the loopback interface
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# allow outgoing connection for dns requests, time synchro on enp53s0 interface
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT

# allow connections on source and destination specific ports on enp53s0 interface
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT

# allow ping in output chain
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -o enp53s0 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables --list shows the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,PSH,URG/FIN,PSH,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: If you cannot reach `localhost:8080` the problem is not the firewall.

Comment: i indeed have a specific issue with the server configuration. 
But the issue still applies to localhost because i can only reach it when applying ACCEPT rule to INPUT when the firewall is activated

Comment: does anything listen on that port? Use e.g. `ss -lnpt | grep 8080` for checking